# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException?

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.class

Comment: Dear Piyush java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex follow that link and Implement all possible solution of that,but still i face same problem :(

Comment: Dear Piyush here is my dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/billdesksdk_1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.2-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
   
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'  
}